# How can I make fizz free and alcohol free mojito?

Tags: fruit, alcohol, drinks, mint

I want to make alcohol free and fizz free mojito. Is this possible? I don't mind carbonated water; but my family does not drink alcohol for religious reasons. We also avoid and have avoided fizzy sugar drinks for years due to harms. My family are just fizz paranoid so we are looking for some alternatives.

Can we make a mojito or something similar? My local takeway gets handfuls of strawberries and blends them up and then with carbonated water and fresh mint leaves serves them up and calls it a strawberry mojito.

Comment: You said you avoid fizzy *sugar* drinks. But you don't need a sweetened carbonated drink to make a mojito, just plain soda water. Are you trying to avoid that too?

Comment: Yes but this only because I have heard all fizzy liquid had side effects. Even plain soda water

Comment: I see. Guess Jolene's answer is the best you can do then. (Unless you want to perhaps go ask your doctor if plain soda water actually has "side effects" besides maybe making you burp.)

Comment: In your question you say that you don't mind carbonated water, so use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harms? Meh, that's silliness. You can make your own fizzy water if you're so inclined. [Sodamakers](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_kk_1?rh=i%3Agarden%2Ck%3Asoda+maker&keywords=soda+maker&ie=UTF8&qid=1408228358).

If you *really* don't want fizzy, then just substitute still water in any of the recipes in a search for [Virgin Mojitos](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=virgin+mojito). Choose recipes that use soda water, club soda or seltzer water, not ginger ale. Ginger ale adds flavor, you want recipes that stand without that flavor.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear; soda water, club soda or seltzer water are all *just* water, injected with carbon dioxide to make bubbles (carbonation). So by substituting regular water for soda water, club soda or seltzer water all you're losing is the "fizzy". (Club soda may have a tiny amount of something like baking soda to neutralize the decrease in PH caused by the carbonation, [Slate](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/05/14/carbonated_waters_defined_what_are_seltzer_club_soda_soda_water_perrier.html) gets further into it, but for all practical purposes, they are all just bubble water.)

Comment: carbonated water will have some of the CO2 form carbonic acid in the water ... so it's not solely bubbles ... but as you mention, it's partially neutralized in club soda.  This higher acid may be a problem for people who already have issues (ulcers, heartburn, GERD, etc.)

Comment: @Joe So if you make your own fizzy water, couldn't you neutralize the acid yourself just as well with a tiny pinch of baking soda?

Comment: it might not be as necessary with homebrew, as there's less time for the reaction to occur ... but I've never tested, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Fantastic answer